# How to Create GI with SubQuery

Tags: acumatica

I have requirement to for  GI of following Query -

Select * from Mtable M, OTable O where M.OrderId=O.OrderId and O.OpId in (Select Min(OpId) from OTable OA where OA.OrderId=O.OrderId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIs are unable to do subqueries, however you can create a GI from a SQL View:

1. Create your view in SQL Server management Studio
2. Create a customization project in Acumatica
3. Create a DAC from your SQL View as follows
   [image: Gen DAC]
4. Add your CREATE VIEW SQL Script into the project as a sql script (don't forget to add a DROP VIEW Statement in the top)
   [image: Add SQL SCript]
5. You can now publish this project anywhere and use the SQL View DAC inside of a generic inquiry

Comment: Will it be compatible with MySQL?

Comment: You can write two scripts, one for MSSQL and one for MYSql and put them both in the "Add script" window. The customization allows for a part of the script to run when its run on a MySql database vs a MSSQL. Press the button "Specify Database Engine" at the bottom of the window